# Getting Started with SyntaxNet (start parsing text right away with Parsey McParseface)

Tags: syntaxnet

I am new to SyntaxNet and I recently tried to install it step by step from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/README.md#instalation.

Although after running bazel test it was said that "Executed 12 out of 12 tests: 12 tests pass" 
 when I used this code

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/git-2.7.4/models/syntaxnet$
echo    'Bob brought the pizza to Alice.' |syntaxnet/demo.sh
```

it gives me this error:

```
syntaxnet/demo.sh: line 31: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval: 
No such file or directory
syntaxnet/demo.sh: line 43: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval: 
No such file or directory
syntaxnet/demo.sh: line 55: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree: 
No such file or directory
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, in case it might be useful to anyone. If you rename or move the path where syntaxnet is installed, you'll break half a dozen symbolic links it creates during installation (it uses absolute paths). In that case, you have to recreate the links with the new path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
To fix it, modify the demo.sh file, lines 31 and 55. 
The locations it points to find parser_eval and conll2tree are wrong, at least they were in my system.

Do a search for "sudo find / -iname 'parser_eval'". 
For me the location of this file was "/home/jesus/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jesus/afbbfe6033ddfb6168467a72894e5682/syntaxnet/bazel-out/local-opt/bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval"
I then proceeded to point line 31 to this location instead of "bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval".

Then did the same for line 55 and conll2tree.
Saved the file, and got it running.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.